# Private method in application controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following the book Agile Development with Rails([http://www.amazon.com/Agile-Development-Rails-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356549](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356549)). In Chapter 9, it defines a private method in application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery

    private

    def current_cart 
      Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      cart = Cart.create
      session[:cart_id] = cart.id
     cart
   end
end
```

It says "This makes this method only available to other controllers, and in particular it prevents Rails from ever making it available as an action on the controller." I am wondering why this will make a private method available to other controllers? Iknow private methods can only be accessible inside the same class. Is there any magic behind this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Private methods in ruby don't work the same way as they do in other languages. In ruby **we can call a private method from within the class it is declared in as well as all subclasses of that class**. This explains why you can declare a private method in ApplicationController and have it available in all other controllers, as all of your other controllers are inherited from ApplicationController.

For more information I suggest researching ruby access control. To start, there is a great article [here](http://www.skorks.com/2010/04/ruby-access-control-are-private-and-protected-methods-only-a-guideline/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Most Rails controllers inherit from the application controller, hence the dependency call as
 
    MyController < ApplicationController::Base

This gives all other controllers with this dependency access to the private methods of the referenced controller.